# Load Oracle 11g data to HDFS using flume

Tags: oracle11g, flume

Is there a way to use flume to transmit my Oracle 11g Database data to HDFS?
I know flume is made for logs and Sqoop should be use to transmit data from Database. But is there a way to use flume instead of Sqoop? What should I do if I want to use this kind of architecture?

Comment: Steven BENET: Did you find any thing other than the below answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The other way to do is For the present data in oracle you can run sqoop and for the subsequent changes you can use [Linked in databus](https://github.com/linkedin/databus) for change data capture(CDC) which can post messages to Kafka. 
Messages from kafka can be easily consumed by Flume.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look in to

1)  [Oracle Golden gate](https://blogs.oracle.com/dataintegration/entry/streaming_relational_transactions_to_flume)

2) [Streaming Oracle Database Logs to HDFS with Flume](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/11093.streaming-oracle-database-logs-to-hdfs-with-flume)

Comment: If I uderstand well, I cannot use that method directly on my current oracle 11g database: I need first to get this OGG product, right ?